# Fitz draw_rect coordination

Tags: python, pdf

I am struggling with right coordination of square to overlap the name field in pdf file.
This is my pdf file

```
https://docdro.id/wiAwsH8
```

I would like to get this

[image]

This is my code

```
import fitz
    page = fitz.open('ABCZ01S0112_Canon iR-ADV C256_1388_0012.pdf')
    for p in page:
        # For every page, draw a rectangle on coordinates (1,1)(100,100)
        p.draw_rect([100,0,5,500],  color = (0, 0, 0), width = 100)
    # Save pdf
    page.save('name.pdf')
```

But still I am not able to find right coordinations

Comment: Your problem seems to only occur if the page is rotated - right? The reason is that PyMuPDF returns and accepts all coordinates with respect to the **_unrotated_** page. So rectangle (1,1)(100,100) always pertaines to the unrotated page. Indeed it is ambiguous to say "I mean rect (1,1)(100,100)"  if you don't add "with respect to (un-) rotated page". If you **mean** wrt to rotated page, you must multiply your rectangle with the page's rotation matrix and use the result in your draw method: `rect * page.rotation_matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't download your PDF file so this is only a guess: try adding `page.mediabox.y0` to your rectangle's `y` coordinates, for example:

```
    p.draw_rect([100, 0 + p.mediabox.y0, 5, 500 + p.mediabox.y0],  color = (0, 0, 0), width = 100)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. But unfortunately not working. I have reuploaded my pdf

Comment: As a general comment, just overlaying an image with a drawing or whatever will not render the data underneath undetectable. To achieve legally stable results, true redaction annotations must be used. Second, to locate the name in a non trial-and-error way, one could use PyMuPDF's OCR API, search for data to be protected and **then** apply redactions to the thus identified rectangles.